# Setting sleep time in delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Ok,a simple question. I want to change sleep time for my delayed job worker. How do I do it in the current version?

I've found out two suggestions for this:

`Delayed::Worker.const_set("SLEEP", sleep_time_in_seconds)`

and

`Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = sleep_time_in_seconds`.

What's the difference between those two?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what version of delayed_job you are using. If you are using the `tobi` version (https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) you should set the constant:

```
Delayed::Worker.const_set('SLEEP', sleep_time_in_seconds)
```

If you don't know what version you are using, the `tobi` version is most likely it (you can check the `delayed_job.gemspec` file in your plugin directory to confirm; it will have something like `s.homepage = <git-page-of-your-version>`).

If you are using the `collectiveidea` version (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) you should use the attribute setter:

```
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = sleep_time_in_seconds
```

If you are using another version, consult the `README` for that version.