# Is it normal to use sleep in delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I added background job to my application using [collectiveidea/delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Job must be recurring with small delay (5 seconds) between launches.

Job code:

```
MyJob = Struct.new(:item_id) do
    def perform
        result = some_method(item_id)
        if result.nil?
            Delayed::Job.enqueue MyJob.new(item_id)
        end
    end
end
```

I edited `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb`:

```
...
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 5
...
```

But jobs launched immediately after previous job finished both before and after editing.
[Here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/333) wrote that `sleep_delay` has another purpose.

Then I added `sleep` (from Ruby kernel) command to job code:

```
MyJob = Struct.new(:item_id) do
    def perform
        result = some_method(item_id)
        if result.nil?
            sleep 5
            Delayed::Job.enqueue MyJob.new(item_id)
        end
    end
end
```

It works as I expected, but is it normal to use `sleep` in `delayed_job` code? Or system schedulers as `cron` are more preferred?

Comment: `Delayed::Worker.const_set('SLEEP', sleep_time_in_seconds)` hope it will work

Comment: Not helped :( As I understand from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596702/setting-sleep-time-in-delayed-job), it's same parameter, but for [tobi/delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job)